# Regex Question: How can I check if any of values in list are matched?

Tags: python, regex

I want to create a RE object that matches if the string contains at least one of the elements of a list.

For example, if `bad_words["censored","stupid","idiot"]` is the list, the RE would match if at least one of them exist.

This is my RE: `re.compile("(%s)+" % ("|".join(bad_words)), re.IGNORECASE)`

Problem is that 'youareanidiot' doesn't match. What do I have to change in order to make it matched?

Comment: Do you mean *contain* instead of *consists*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using re.match? Try re.search. See [Matching vs. Searching](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching) from the Python regex docs.

```
import re
bad_words = ["stupid", "idiot"]
regex = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(word) for word in bad_words), re.IGNORECASE)
print regex.search('youareanidiot').group()

# prints "idiot"
```

Answer (score 11):

While it's possible to do this with a regular expression, I think you are better off without a regex here.  To test a string `s` against `bad_words`, try something like

```
s = s.lower()
any(bad in s for bad in bad_words)
```

Your `bad_words` should all be lower case.

Comment: I just did some tests - looks like CPython's compiled regex will beat the "in" lookup by a noticeable difference if the string being searched is over a certain threshold (equalized at about 500 chars for me). also looks like CPython's "in" increases in complexity for longer strings even if the match is at the start :)

Comment: @lunixbochs: Interesting -- especially the last statement!  By "better off" I didn't really mean performance, but rather code readability and avoiding pitfalls.  E.g. your code does not quote the items of `bad_words` for the use in the regular expression using `re.escape()`, which might introduce hard-to-find errors at a later time.

Comment: good point on escape - I didn't really think to modify his regex line aside from the bad match vs search... I also realized he's spending extra time on the + match. the new code without group or + ran slightly faster even on that short 'youareanidiot' string!

Comment: more tests - compiled regex looks faster if the match is near the beginning, 'in' looks faster if it's near the end. at this point I'd go for your implementation for simplicity `any(bad.lower() in s for bad in bad_words)` :)